# Python List/Dataframe to Dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Hello guys I have a question regarding convert List/Dataframe to Dict.

My current data:

```
Column header: a
Rows = b , c , d , e
```

How do convert this into a dict with this format?

```
Keys = rows
Value = a: rows
```

I have a list to do it, but I can convert it into a dataframe to do it also.

Comment: To give a better answer, please provide more details. What type is your data? Strings, Int, Other? Also, please give a more specific example of the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is all strings:

```
new_dict = {}
for row in rows:
    new_dict[row] = f'{column_header} {row}'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can convert list to dictionary by the following example

   Example 1: list to dictionary with list element as key in dictionary

   ```
   list = ["development", "testing", "backend", "frontend"]
   dictionary = {i:5 for i in list}
   ```

   Example 2: Converting a list to dictionary with list elements as values in dictionary

   ```
   list = ["development", "testing", "backend", "frontend"]
   dictionary = { i : list[i] for i in range(0, len(list) )}
   ```
2. You can use pandas if you have a set of dataframe like as follows

   Example:

   ```
        0        1           2
   0    Khushi  34      Sydeny
   1   Parnika  30       Delhi
   2  Srinidhi  16    New York
   3    Shobha  30  Washington
   ```

   For example the above dataframe is stored in variable called dataframe then we can convert to dictionary as

   ```
   dataframe.to_dict()
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   {0: {0: 'Khushi', 1: 'Parnika', 2: 'Srinidhi', 3: 'Shobha'},
   1: {0: 34, 1: 30, 2: 16, 3: 30},
   2: {0: 'Sydeny', 1: 'Delhi', 2: 'New York', 3: 'Washington'}}
   ```

Comment: Please provide some example. 'you can use something' is not good enough